# Beanstalkd doesn't write logs

Tags: logging, ubuntu-14.04, beanstalkd

I am running beanstalkd on ubuntu 14.04
My question is that I don't see any logs from this service at all.

Of course I have made entries in defaults, as well as I tried to change init.d script. But it seems beanstalk doesn't make any logging at all or I am doing something wrong.

Here is init.d script content. @Pentium10, Seems you are right - the only couple of palces I found in source code are this one: https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/157d88bf9435a23b71a1940a9afb617e52a2b9e9/pkg/beanstalkd.spec.in#L4
 https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/157d88bf9435a23b71a1940a9afb617e52a2b9e9/sd-daemon.h#L83

**/etc/init.d/beanstalkd** file

```
...

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

...

DAEMON=/usr/bin/beanstalkd # Introduce the server's location here
NAME=beanstalkd             # Introduce the short server's name here
DESC="in-memory queueing server" # Introduce a short description here
#LOGDIR=/var/log/beanstalkd  # Log directory to use

...


#LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/$NAME.log  # Server logfile
DAEMONUSER=beanstalkd   # Users to run the daemons as. If this value
                        # is set start-stop-daemon will chuid the server
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no log being created by beanstalkd.

Comment: @Pentium10, I took a look on to the init.d script and there is LOG_DIR and LOG_FILE directives are present.

Comment: Which init script? Can you link it?

Comment: @Pentium10, added small update.

Comment: Maybe this is incomplete job or undocumented, you shall place a github issue inquiring about log setup.

Comment: @Pentium10, thanks. I'll proceed like that.

Comment: I think the best you can do is to run it manually and increase the verbosity of the output: `beanstalkd -VV`

Comment: `beanstalkd -h` says `-b DIR write-ahead log directory`